# Model and solve nutrition optimization problem: how to?

Tags: constrained-optimization, linear-programming

How to solve/assess the following problem?

**Given**: $N$ ingredients like apples, bread etc. Mass of an ingredient $j$ is in this simplified model a sum of macro nutrients carbohydrates, proteins and fats in proportions $c_j$, $p_j$ and $f_j$:

$(1)\ M_j = (c_j + p_j + f_j) * x_j $ (in grams)

$(2) \ c_j + p_j + f_j = 1$

Also a nutrition model is provided,

$ (3) A_c + B_p + C_p = 1$.

**Problem**: find optimal quantities $x_j$ of ingredients so that total mass possibly fulfils the provided nutrition model, i.e.

$ (4) \ M_{total} = x1 * M1 + x_j + M_j * x_j .. + M_N * x_N $

where

$$ (5) \sum_{j=1}^n c_j / M_{total} = A_c$$
$$ (6) \sum_{j=1}^n p_j / M_{total} = B_p$$
$$ (7) \sum_{j=1}^n f_j / M_{total} = C_f$$

From my current knowledge state, I assume this is a linear programming problem which can be approached for example using a solver like Python's PuLP. So I will try to get my head [around it](https://realpython.com/linear-programming-python/) but if I'm going in completely wrong direction I hope an answer here will point me to another more suitable method.

**Example:**

- Say we want to consume 1500 kcal (being on a diet, typically adults eat about 2000 plus something kcal which is on a smaller detail level an individual value based on sex, age, weight and physical activity level aka PAL)
- A possible recommendation is to have these calories as a "budget" distributed between 55% carbohydrates, 15% proteins and 30% fat. All that keto and low-carb stuff is basically how these three parameters are weighted.
- Now we know we should eat accrodingly the "calorical vector" `[825.0000000000001, 225.0, 450.0]` or recomputed to mass in grams using reference values `[201, 55, 48]`
- A random menu more or less close to that could be then for example like: "*1489 kcal = 25g butter, 85g Emmenthal, 180g turkey breast, 800 g banana*"

## Modeling approach 1

- Decision variables: mass values for macro-nutrients; `c_banana` for total carb value in optimal banana quantity.
- Constraints: need to tell the program what separate nutrients contain and what's diet goal
- Optimization objective: while eating that less calories, let's optimize for max mass of this healthy food.

*Encountered problems*

How do I actually model that banana contains 21% carbohydrates? The naive guess,

```
model += (c_banana /(c_banana + p_banana + f_banana) == 0.21, "banana_c")
```

leads to the following error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for /: 'LpVariable' and 'LpAffineExpression'
```

Comment: What are the optimization variables? What is the objective function? What are the constraints? Once you've determined all that, it should be very straightforward.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone hi there, thank you for your quick response. Please help me to formalize better starting from the actual layman problem: I've got some bread, butter, eggs and apples\* and want to plan a menu to fulfil given proportions of macronutrients 1= A+ B +C; I obviously need help to translate details of the task to make the problem description complete.  \* the other day these can be other ingridients.

Comment: The first step is to choose and define optimization variables. Then write out the objective function and constraints. If the model is a Linear Programming problem, the objective function and all constraints must be linear with respect to the optimization variables.

Comment: There is something off with your first two equations. Are $c_j, p_j, and f_j$  *masses*, or are they *percentages*. I ask because the second sum expression makes sense for percentages, and the first equation makes sense for total masses.

Comment: @MPIchael thank you for your comment and pointing to the built-in math feature :-) Hope now fixed and restyled makes more sense.

Comment: @MarkL.Stone I've defined the required assets.

Comment: I think you've made a mistake by including the factor $x_j$ in both equation (1) and equation (4).  If it's not a mistake, then this is not a linear program.